# Switching between two frames on seperate files in tkinter

Tags: python, file, class, tkinter, import

I am writing a program where I have the opportunity, to switch between two frames which are one two separate Files. The main file is called "Main_Menu" while the other file is called "first_page". When I import the classes from both classes into each other, then I get an circular import which leads to the program not working. Does anybody have a solution? The codes to both files are under this Text.

Main_Menu.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import PhotoImage

from second_page import SecondPage
from first_page import FirstPage

class Hauptfenster: 
  def init(self, root): 
    self.root = root self.root.title("Hauptfenster")    

    # Bild laden
    self.background_image = PhotoImage(file="Background_Main.png")

    # Größe des Bildes abrufen
    self.width = self.background_image.width()
    self.height = self.background_image.height()

    # Haupt frame erstellen
    self.main_frame = tk.Frame(self.root, width=self.width, height=self.height)
    self.main_frame.pack_propagate(False)  # Verhindert, dass der Rahmen seine Größe an die Widgets anpasst
    self.main_frame.pack()  # Packe den Haupt frame, um ihn sichtbar zu machen

    # Hintergrundbild hinzufügen
    self.background_label = tk.Label(self.main_frame, image=self.background_image)
    self.background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)  # Füllt das Bild den Rahmen aus

    # Rahmen für den ersten Knopf erstellen
    self.create_character_frame = tk.Frame(self.main_frame, bg="white", bd=0, relief="flat")
    self.create_character_frame.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.7, anchor="center")

    # Rahmen für den zweiten Knopf erstellen
    self.Archiv_frame = tk.Frame(self.main_frame, bg="white", bd=0, relief="flat")
    self.Archiv_frame.place(relx=0.6, rely=0.7, anchor="center")

    # Rahmen für den schließen Button
    self.close_frame = tk.Frame(self.main_frame, bg="white", bd=0, relief="flat")
    self.close_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.9, anchor="center")

    # Rahmen für das Logo
    self.logo_frame = tk.Frame(self.main_frame, bg="white", bd=0, relief="flat")
    self.logo_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.2, anchor="center")

    # Text für den ersten Knopf hinzufügen
    self.create_character_image = PhotoImage(file="character_text.png")
    self.create_character_button = tk.Button(self.create_character_frame, image=self.create_character_image,
                                             relief="flat", command=self.zeige_erste_seite)
    self.create_character_button.pack(pady=10)

    # Bild für den ersten Knopf hinzufügen

    self.first_image = PhotoImage(file="Bild_eins.png")
    self.first_image_label = tk.Label(self.main_frame, image=self.first_image, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
    self.first_image_label.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.511, anchor="center")

    # Text für den zweiten Knopf hinzufügen
    self.Archiv_image = PhotoImage(file="Archiv_Text.png")  # Beispielbild, ersetze es mit deinem Bild
    self.Archiv_button = tk.Button(self.Archiv_frame, image=self.Archiv_image, relief="flat",
                                   command=self.zeige_zweite_seite)
    self.Archiv_button.pack(pady=10)

    # Bild für den zweiten Knopf hinzufügen
    self.Sheet_image = PhotoImage(file="Bild_zwei.png")
    self.Sheet_image_label = tk.Label(self.main_frame, image=self.Sheet_image, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
    self.Sheet_image_label.place(relx=0.6, rely=0.511, anchor="center")

    # Button zum Schließen des Programms hinzufügen
    self.close_image = PhotoImage(file="Escape.png")
    self.close_button = tk.Button(self.close_frame, image=self.close_image, command=root.destroy, relief="flat")
    self.close_button.pack(pady=10)

    # Logo einfügen
    self.logo_image = PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
    self.logo_image_label = tk.Label(self.main_frame, image=self.logo_image, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
    self.logo_image_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.2, anchor="center")

def zeige_erste_seite(self):
    # Alles im Haupt frame löschen
    for widget in self.main_frame.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    # Erstelle ein Objekt der Klasse für die erste Seite
    FirstPage(self.main_frame)

def zeige_zweite_seite(self):
    # Alles im Haupt frame löschen
    for widget in self.main_frame.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    # Erstelle ein Objekt der Klasse für die zweite Seite
    SecondPage(self.main_frame)

def main(): 
    root = tk.Tk() 
    app = Hauptfenster(root) 
    root.mainloop()

if name == "main": main()
```

first_page.py

```
import tkinter as tk

from Main_Menu import Hauptfenster

class FirstPage(tk.Frame): 
  def init(self, parent): 
    self.parent = parent 
    self.frame = tk.Frame(self.parent) 
    self.frame.pack(expand=True, fill='both')  

    # Neuen Inhalt für die zweite Seite hinzufügen
    label = tk.Label(self.frame, text="Das ist die erste Seite")
    label.pack()

    # Button zum Hauptmenü hinzufügen
    self.back_to_main_button = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Zurück zum Hauptmenü", command=self.back_to_main)
    self.back_to_main_button.pack()

def back_to_main(self):
    # Alles im Frame löschen
    for widget in self.frame.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    # Erstelle ein Objekt der Klasse für das Hauptmenü
    Hauptfenster(self.parent)
```

I wanted to switch between those two while they are on separate files.

Comment: Simple way is to pass the class reference to `FirstPage`, then you don't need to import the class from `Main_Menu`.  However how you create the instance of class inside `FirstPage.back_to_main()` is wrong because you pass a frame object to it but it expects a *root* window.  You need to think again your design carefully.